Regarding matrix transformation
Given a matrix transformation $T:M \to N$, such that $N = TMT^{-1}$ that takes a matrix $N$ to another matrix $N$. If $[M]_{ij} = f_{ij}(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ depend linearly on scalars $x_k: k=1,\dots,n$, then is it guaranteed that $[N]_{ij}$ would also depend on linearly on the same and all scalars?
To be precise, is it possible prove or disprove that $ [N]_{ij}$:

depend on less number of scalars say it does not contain $x_r$ for some $r=1,\dots,n$,
contains a term of the form $x_k^{p}$, where $p\ne 1$?


Your question makes no sense. Writing that $T$ is a transformation and $T:M \to N$ implies that $M$ and $N$ are sets (vector spaces) of some kind, but you say that $M$ and $N$ are matrices

@BenGrossmann, I apologise for my lack of knowledge. I am have a humble math background.  In my case, T is a matrix that ofcouse takes a vector $u$ to another vector $v$ as $Tu = v$. But then it also "transforms" matrices as a similarity transformation $N = TMT^{-1}$.

Here's the two questions that I think you're trying to ask.

We are given that $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^{m \times m}$ is linear, and that $\Phi:\Bbb R^{m \times m} \to \Bbb R^{m \times m}$ is the map $\Phi(M) = TMT^{-1}$ for some invertible $T \in \Bbb R^{m \times m}$. Given that:

$\mathbf x = (x_1,\dots,x_n)$
$M = f(\mathbf x)$
$N = \Phi(M)$


Can we guarantee that $N$ depends linearly on the entries of $\mathbf x$?
Can we guarantee that each $N_{ij}$ depends on the same numbers entries of $\mathbf x$ as $M_{ij}$?


The answer to question 1 is yes. We can write $N = (\Phi \circ f)(\mathbf x)$, and $\Phi \circ f$ is the composition of linear maps, making it a linear map.
The answer to question 2 is no. Here is a simple counterexample.
$$
T = \pmatrix{1 & 1\\1 & -1}, \quad f(x_1,x_2) = \pmatrix{x_1 +x_2 & x_1 - x_2\\x_1 - x_2 & x_1 + x_2}.
$$
We find that
$$
N = \Phi(f(\mathbf x)) =  
\pmatrix{2x_1 & 0\\
0 & 2x_2}.
$$
All entries of $M$ depend on both $x_1$ and $x_2$, but the entries of $N$ depend on at most one entry of $\mathbf x$.

Thanks @BenGrossmann, you got my first question right. But in (2) I meant to ask "is there any $x_k$ that appears in $M$, does not appear in $N$"? In other words, some $x_k's$ are disappearing because of the transformation?

@Mike I see. See my latest edit

Thanks Ben. Could it happen that $N$ just depends on only $x_1$ or only $x_2$? Doesn't matter in which matrix element of $N$ they appear? I mean can there be "loss" of any $x_k$ under the transformation?

@Mike No. "Losing" an $x_k$ is not a reversible process, but the transformation $\Phi$ is invertible
